# Update Data from Collection Form in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I can't find how to update data in form collection to database, like in normal Edit action, the EditForm generated and pass to UpdateAction. I can make form for EditForm but can't find how to update data to database.

[How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) is showing how to add and delete it using persist and remove but how to bind it from post data and update it into database? My collection actually just entity without table in database. It's used just for population many fields from my primary entity DftAbsensi into single form.

This is my primary entity DftAbsensi (without getter and setter):

```
<?php

namespace Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    class DftAbsensi
    {
    private $id;

    private $tanggal;

    private $status;
```

This is the collection entity for Absensi :

```
<?php    
namespace Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity;    
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class CollectionAbsensi
{
    private $statusS;

    private $tanggal;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tanggalS = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->statusS = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setTanggal($tanggal)
    {
        $this->tanggal = $tanggal;    
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTanggal()
    {
        return $this->tanggal;
    }

    public function setStatusS(ArrayCollection $statusS)
    {
        $this->statusS = $statusS;    
        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatusS()
    {
        return $this->statusS;
    }   
}
```

This is DftAbsensiType :

```
<?php

namespace Sifo\AdminBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class DftAbsensiType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', 'text', array('required'  => false))
            ->add('status', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => array('H' => 'Hadir', 'A' => 'Tanpa Keterangan', 'S' => 'Sakit', 'I' => 'Izin', 'L' => 'Libur'),
                'required'  => false, 
                'empty_value' => '- Pilih -'))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\DftAbsensi'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sifo_adminbundle_dftabsensi';
    }
}
```

Actually I'm using collection just for populating many fields from databases. Persist database just in my primary entity DftAbsensi above. This is Collection for Absensi Type :

```
<?php

namespace Sifo\AdminBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CollectionAbsensiType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('tanggal', 'date', array('label' => false, 'required'  => false, 'attr'=>array('style'=>'display:none;'), 'widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
            ->add('statusS', 'collection', array(
                'label' => false, 
                'options'  => array('label' => false, 'required'  => false),
                'type' => new DftAbsensiType())
        );
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\CollectionAbsensi'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sifo_adminbundle_collectionabsensi';
    }
}
```

This is how to population data in my controller. This form used for EditForm :

```
<?php

namespace Sifo\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\DftAbsensi;
use Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\CollectionAbsensi;
use Sifo\AdminBundle\Form\CollectionAbsensiType;
use Sifo\AdminBundle\Form\DftAbsensiType;

/**
 * DftAbsensi controller.
 *
 */
class DftAbsensiController extends Controller
{
public function manageAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $emGrupPelajar = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityGrupPelajar = $emGrupPelajar->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:DftGrupPelajar')->findByIdGrup($id);

    /* check tanggal and set if exist */
    $tanggal = $request->request->get('sifo_adminbundle_collectionabsensi')['tanggal'];
    if($tanggal == NULL) 
        $tanggal = $request->request->get('form')['tanggal'];
    $tanggal = new \DateTime($tanggal);

    /* Show data */
    $emShow = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $collectionAbsensi = new CollectionAbsensi();
    foreach ($entityGrupPelajar as $temp) {
        $entity = new DftAbsensi();
        $entity = $emShow->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:DftAbsensi')->findOneBy(array('idGrupPelajar' => $temp, 'tanggal' => $tanggal));
        if ($entity)
        {
            $entityPelajar = $emShow->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:MstPelajar')->find($temp->getIdPelajar());
            $dftAbsensi = new DftAbsensi();
            $dftAbsensi->setId($entity->getId())
                ->setIdGrupPelajar($entity->getIdGrupPelajar())
                ->setStatus($entity->getStatus())
            ;
            $collectionAbsensi->getStatusS()->add($dftAbsensi);
            $collectionAbsensi->setTanggal($tanggal); 
        }
    }
    $emShow->flush();

    $formEdit = $this->createForm(new CollectionAbsensiType(), $collectionAbsensi, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_absensi_update', array('id' => $id)),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));                   
    $formEdit->add('save', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-info')));

    return $this->render('SifoAdminBundle:DftAbsensi:manage.html.twig', array(
        'form_refresh'   => $formRefresh->createView(),
        'form_edit'      => $formEdit->createView(),
        'user'           => $user,
    ));
}
```

As mentioned before, my CollectionAbsensi actually just used for population fields from databases. But for updating I'm using DftAbsensi Entity. There is no table for CollectionAbsensi in my databases. This is how I update the data:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $emGrupPelajar = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityGrupPelajar = $emGrupPelajar->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:DftGrupPelajar')->findByIdGrup($id);

    /* set tanggal */
    $tanggal = new \DateTime($request->request->get('sifo_adminbundle_collectionabsensi')['tanggal']);

    /* populate data */
    $emShow = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $collectionAbsensi = new CollectionAbsensi();
    foreach ($entityGrupPelajar as $temp) {
        $entity = new DftAbsensi();
        $entity = $emShow->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:DftAbsensi')->findOneBy(array('idGrupPelajar' => $temp, 'tanggal' => $tanggal));
        if ($entity)
        {
            $entityPelajar = $emShow->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:MstPelajar')->find($temp->getIdPelajar());
            $dftAbsensi = new DftAbsensi();
            $dftAbsensi->setId($entity->getId())
                ->setIdGrupPelajar($entity->getIdGrupPelajar())
                ->setStatus($entity->getStatus())
            ;
            $collectionAbsensi->getStatusS()->add($dftAbsensi);
            $collectionAbsensi->setTanggal($tanggal);
        }
    }

    $formEdit = $this->createForm(new CollectionAbsensiType(), $collectionAbsensi);                  
    $formEdit->handleRequest($request);
    $emShow->flush();

    $response = $this->forward('SifoAdminBundle:DftAbsensi:manage', array(
        'id' => $id,
        'request' => $request,
    ));
    return $response;
}
```

There is no error from this code. The problem is the databases not updated when I press Save button. I confused for binding data and how to update them into database in updateAction above. Can a collection form not be used for updating data?

My form is attendance system which look like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is still not really answer my question about "How to update data in form collection?". I do update my data with old way : **Get all the data from request manually and bind it to entity then update it into database.**

Here my code :

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    /* get request */
    $data = $request->request->get('sifo_adminbundle_collectionabsensi')['statusS'];

    /* update data */
    $total = count($data);
    for ($i = 0; $i < ($total / 2); $i++) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:DftAbsensi')->find($data[$i]['id']);
        if ($entity){
            $entity->setStatus($data[$i]['status'])
                   ->setOperator($user->getNama());
            $em->flush();
        }
    }

    $response = $this->forward('SifoAdminBundle:DftAbsensi:manage', array(
        'id' => $id,
        'request' => $request,
    ));
    return $response;
}
```

If someone has a better idea, post your answer here.